# Using themes and resources

Tags: asp.net

I have a site that uses asp.net themes and it uses i18n.

Some images are specified on resource file because they have texts on it.

When I tried to add an item like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton SkinID="ImbDisaprove" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Images, Disaprove %>" />
```

I receive an error saying that it is not possible to use scripting inside a theme file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation by design. You can use ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Images, Disaprove %>" in aspx.